# Is it possible to just update Java through YUM on a licensed RHEL5?

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel5

RHEL 5.6 64 bit running:

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-b07)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b06, mixed mode)
```

Can I update this with the latest build 29 using yum?
if not what is the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

[Sun JRE via RHN](https://rhn.redhat.com/network/software/packages/name_overview.pxt?package_name=java-1.6.0-sun&archIdList=&archLabelList=&search_subscribed_channels=yes)

Add the "supplementary software" channel to the appropriate entitlement in RHN, and you should then be able to

```
yum install java-1.6.0-sun-1.6.0.29*
```

cheers!